# Problem with change of variables

Tags: calculus

I have this integral: $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}xyz\,dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{1}{8}$$
But when I make this change of variables:$$x=t$$$$y=t$$$$z=t$$ I have $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}t^3\,dt\,dt\,dt=\frac{1}{4} ?!$$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the first integral $x$, $y$, and $z$ are distinct variables.  In the second integral you have but one variable, $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is the region you are integrating over (the cube in the first octant with sides parallel to the $x$,$y$, $z$ axes on side length $1$). Then notice that the variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ give you a coordinate system in $D$ where you can describe the location of any point $P$ in $D$. Now, let's say we adjust to your "coordinate system" with $x=y=z=t$. Then we suddenly run into a problem, since now we can no longer describe every point in $D$! Indeed, if $P = (1/2, 1/2, 1/3)$, say, in regular cartesian coordinates, then how would you describe $P$ in your coordinate system? You would need $t = x = 1/2, t = y = 1/2$, and $t = z = 1/3$, meaning that you'd have to deduce that $1/2=1/3$, which is clearly a problem. So, the real problem with your change of coordinates is that it is *not* a change of coordinates. That is, your variable change no longer lets you give coordinates to describe all points in $D$, so you can't integrate over $D$ with this change of variables.

Answer (score 1):

$x,\; y,\;z$ are *different* and *independent*  variables, so they cannot be represented by one variable $t.$ 
You can simply integrate
\begin{gather}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}xyz\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}xyz\,dx\right)\,dy\right)\,dz \\
=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}yz\left(\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx\right)\,dy\right)\,dz\\
=\int_{0}^{1}z\left(\int_{0}^{1}y\left(\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx\right)\,dy\right)\,dz
\\
=\int_{0}^{1}z\,dz \cdot \int_{0}^{1}y\,dy\cdot\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx
\end{gather}

Answer (score 0):

In the original integral, you have three nested integrals.  The innermost integral is $\int_0^1xyzdx$, in which $x$ is the variable of integration while $y,z$ are free variables.  However, when you pass to the alternate integral, now you have $\int_0^1 t\times t\times t dt$, and suddenly you don't have two free variables anymore.  Rather than integrating over all $x,y,z$ independently over $[0,1]$, you've integrated only those $x,y,z$ where $x=y=z$.